# Как свернуть/развернуть приложение на C# через панель задач?

Tags: c#, winforms

Приложение почему то не хочет сворачиваться при клике по иконке в панели задач. Для примера взял `VS`:

[image: иконка в панели задач]

Кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это поправить?

Comment: Для начала, кто вам сказал что VS написано на C#

Comment: Вопрос надобы уточнить, вы говорите про программу которую сами пишете или про какую то чужую программу?

Comment: Причем тут тег icon ?

Comment: Написал простое приложение на WinForm, и при клике по иконке на панели задач, программа не сворачивается и не разворачивается.

Я уже отметил, что VS - это для примера.

Comment: Это базовая функциональность Проводника, которая должна работать если вы ее не сломали.

Comment: Сейчас глянул другую программу. Единственное, что я заметил - формы в borderstyle: none не реагируют на сворачивание/разворачивание.

Comment: У вас десктоп пожрал вирус или как то другим образом сломалась работа проводника. Если вы специально не ограничивали функциональность вашей формы, то все должно работать из коробки так сказать.

Comment: C другими программами (мною написанными) все нормально, с тем же VS - тоже все нормально, все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не сломалось. Было такое, как раз с `FormBorderStyle: None`.
Добавьте в форму:

```
const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DBLCLKS;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180893/7099599

Comment: Большое спасибо!